# How to create a reset button for slot machine game in JS

Tags: javascript, function, button, callback

I have a prototype of a slot machine game coded in JS and I am struggling to create a reset button to restart the game. I was trying to create a second function called playAgain where the main game function is called back but it's clearly not working. Maybe I'm supposed to give it a parameter? Not sure. Help please!

```js
const num1 = document.getElementById("num-1");
const num2 = document.getElementById("num-2");
const num3 = document.getElementById("num-3");
const message = document.getElementById("message")
const button = document.getElementById("button");

const random1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1;
const random2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1;
const random3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1;

button.addEventListener("click", checkEquality);

function checkEquality() {
    num1.innerHTML = random1;
    num2.innerHTML = random2;
    num3.innerHTML = random3;
    if (random1 === random2 && random1 === random3 && random2 === random3) {
        message.innerHTML = "Congratulations, you won!"
    } else {
        message.innerHTML = "Sorry, you lost!"
    }
    button.innerHTML = "GIVE IT ANOTHER GO!"
}
button.addEventListener("click", playAgain)
function playAgain() {
    if(num1 !== "?" && num2 !== "?" && num3 !== "?") {
        message.innerHTML = "";
        checkEquality()
    }
}
```

```html
<h1>Slot Machine</h1>
<div>
    <p id="num-1">?</p>
    <p id="num-2">?</p>
    <p id="num-3">?</p>
</div>
<p id="message"></p>
<button id="button">GIVE IT A GO!</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the random numbers inside your function, otherwise you just use the same numbers.
Also if you use const the value can't be changed anymore.

```js
 const num1 = document.getElementById("num-1");
    const num2 = document.getElementById("num-2");
    const num3 = document.getElementById("num-3");
    const message = document.getElementById("message")
    const button = document.getElementById("button");
    
    button.addEventListener("click", checkEquality);
    
    function checkEquality() {
        var random1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1;
        var random2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1;
        var random3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1;
        num1.innerHTML = random1;
        num2.innerHTML = random2;
        num3.innerHTML = random3;
        if (random1 === random2 && random1 === random3 && random2 === random3) {
            message.innerHTML = "Congratulations, you won!"
        } else {
            message.innerHTML = "Sorry, you lost!"
        }
        button.innerHTML = "GIVE IT ANOTHER GO!"
    }
    button.addEventListener("click", playAgain)
    function playAgain() {
        if(num1 !== "?" && num2 !== "?" && num3 !== "?") {
            message.innerHTML = "";
            checkEquality()
        }
    }
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Slot Machine</h1>
        <div>
            <p id="num-1">?</p>
            <p id="num-2">?</p>
            <p id="num-3">?</p>
        </div>
        <p id="message"></p>
        <button id="button">GIVE IT A GO!</button>
        
    
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!... and here I thought I needed to come up with something complicated :(. I thought that creating something inside a function meant that piece of code wouldn't be "modified", that's why I put the random numbers in the global scope. Why would putting them outside of the function give back always the same numbers?

Comment: First you define them as a `const`, so the values can't be changed.

Comment: Second: you generate the random numbers just once, if you open your window. So your function worked before but give always the same random numbers.

Comment: Third: If you put something inside a function, you can't modified them if you are outside of the function (atleast if you declare it as `let`) (https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let )

Comment: Point number 2 is clearer :) basically if outside the function, the numbers are generated just once. Inside the function they're called every time the function is called. And they're not "set" because... well, they're random. Makes perfect sense now! I know about const/let and their differences in theory... this teaches me I will use const only to select and store elements in variables from now on. Just to be a little bit safer! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Great that I could help you! :-) And to be honest javascript isn't the easiest language at the beginning. Could you also please check my answer as the correct one. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is you are using the same button for both of the action.

fix :

```
button.removeEventListener("click",checkEquality);
button.addEventListener("click",playAgain);
```

in the check equality..function
and similarly you can do it for playAgain function.